# Why am I unable to access function properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a function with refernece to callback functions. However I cannot seem to access its properties.

```
const example = (
   callback: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown
): void => ({
   name: callback.name // <- errors
   // ...
})
```

My issue is, [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) doesn't like me accessing the funciton properties.

```
name: callback.name 
// ts(2339): Property 'name' does not exist on type '(...args: any[]) => any'
```

What would be the correct way of accessing the function name (or other [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) properties for that matter)?

> Typescript version: "`ˆ3.9.7`" *(latest as to the day of this post)*

Comment: Could you try type casting `<any>callback.name`

Comment: @ZeroWorks the error persists even if you do that

Comment: that's stange, but your code seems work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQQBQQIYBssCMMQDWAXIqgHSUYBOA5gM6kZgCeA2gLoCUiAvAHyJmLHgG8AUIimIo1FognSliTDnxFUXANyTpAXxUYoEABZkApmN3KVCenCznyWOLXTY8BQuTAYAtpbWiHriekA

Comment: @Grundy strange indeed. I mean if I even suppress the error, it works properly. I suspect this error might actually be explicit for vscode inbuilt typescript support.

Comment: this version from project, or from vscode? You can try setup vscode - use typescript from project

Comment: Did you tried double question mark, AKA Nullish Coalescing on callback?

Comment: can you try `(callback as any).name`

Comment: Lol... @AkashDathan... I forgot brackets!

Comment: Do you get this error if you run `tsc` from command line?

Comment: @Grundy my `typescript.tsdk` is set to `null` (so if I'm not mistaken it should default to the project one)

Comment: @AkashDathan `(<any>callback).name` technically does suppress the typescript error, but to be honest, I'm not exactly thrilled with this. It really does feel like only a workaround by supressing typescript type control rather than solving the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright I found what caused it and how to fix it.
This issue occured because of how my `tsconfig.json` was set up inside my project.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    // ....
  },
}
```

**Reason being `interface Functon` has only been declared in `lib.es6.d.ts`**

So depending on the needs, in order to solve this, you can

- Either upgrade the target version in `tsconfig.json`

  ```js
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es6" // was "es5"
       // ...
    }
  }
  ```
- Or specify the `"lib"` to be included in compilation

  ```js
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017", "es5"], // needs at least es6
       // ...
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'
import { FieldType, ErrorType } from 'types/FieldTypes'

const handleErrors = (
  setField: Dispatch<SetStateAction<FieldType>>,
  callback: {
    name: 'name of callback',
    run: (args) => {
      try {
        callback.run();
      } catch (e) {
      const newError: ErrorType = {
        name: callback.name,
        message: e.message,
      };
      setField((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        errors: [...prevData.errors || [], newError],
      });
    }
  }
);
```